# Native prepared statements: are they so limited?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

An informative-sounding [blog post](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/apr/using-pdo-mysql/) from 2006 states these facts about using native prepared statements in PDO:

1. Native prepared statements cannot take advantage of the query cache, resulting in lower performance.
2. Native prepared statements cannot execute certains types of queries, such as "SHOW TABLES".
3. Native prepared statements don't correctly communicate column lengths for certain other "SHOW" queries, resulting in garbled results.

How much of this is still true today?

Comment: Maybe on [programmers.se]? Not sure though

Comment: First of all , it deals with early release of PDO. Nobody was recommending to use it at that stage. Also, the author is recommending to use emulated prepares .. that should be enough for you to dismiss him/her as misguided.

Comment: (1) and (2) are certainly untrue, I've never encountered (3) but I cannot vouch for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not true if you are using a recent MySQL version. At least to the most part.

1. Prepared statements make use of the query cache [since MySQL 5.1.17](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html).
2. Nearly all SQL statements can be run as prepared statements. You can find a [list in the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). `SHOW TABLES` in particular is not in that list, but in all honestly, have you ever used that SQL statement from PHP?
3. I don't know anything about that, but I'd assume that it is fixed.

Don't forget that the emulation of prepared statements is **not encoding-safe** and as such may (depending on the exact condition) still allow SQL injections.

Answer (score 3):

1. falae. As of MySQL 5.1.17 [the query cache works with prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html)
2. Why would you need to prepare a statement to do a SHOW TABLES?
3. Can you cite a source for that?  I've personally not had any issues

Comment: Thanks. The text is an exact quote from [this page](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/apr/using-pdo-mysql/).

Comment: That page is over 6 years old.  I'm sure there's been a few bug fixes since then!  One real problem the PHP community has is the sheer volume of old information floating around.  You have to be careful of claims made in pages on the topic of PHP, and one really good indicator as to reliability is age.  The older an article is, the more likely it is to have gone out of date.